# Why react native flatlist render one by one

Tags: react-native

This is the screen itself:

[image]

The code for the flatlist is:

```js
<FlatList
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingBottom: 40,
  }}
  data={data}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{height: 10}}/>}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => m.extraKey(item)}
/>
```

And the data is from server, but only fetch once. the code is:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  c_service.getAllTags()
    .then((res: LabelItemBean[]) => {
      res.forEach(item => initLabels(item, selected));

      setPreData(res);
      setData(() => res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
  });
}, []);
```

I can't figure out why it renders one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parameter `initialNumToRender` to set how many items will be rendered at first (When loaded).

You can also use `maxToRenderPerBatch` to define how many items will render every time you reach the end of the flatlist.

Your code should work better now if used like this:

```js
<FlatList
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingBottom: 40,
  }}
  data={data}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={30}
  initialNumToRender={50}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{height: 10}}/>}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => m.extraKey(item)}
 />
```

See [here](https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b), for more informations about how these parameters impact on the performance of your flatlist.